# How to write text on a grid

Tags: html, css, grid

This is one of the first project I'm making for practice. To make a resume, I initially divided the window into 2 parts using grid. When I tried to type the text in the grid, the text shifted the grid downwards. So please tell me about the changes I'll have to make in order to solve my problem.

please check my code--

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-side">
            <div class="leftpart1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi obcaecati est placeat asperiores dolorum quos, ab, quisquam odit vel exercitationem, nostrum ad! Fugiat quos, molestias ratione aliquid a blanditiis asperiores deserunt, expedita beatae quas quam magni earum alias debitis provident. Sapiente vel asperiores excepturi, vitae explicabo iure sed nihil, ea dolore facilis pariatur officiis cupiditate odio iusto, laborum voluptas officia aliquam veritatis perspiciatis quaerat! Expedita aliquam molestiae facere esse, accusantium temporibus voluptatem placeat ullam nulla sit dolores architecto consequatur pariatur quos illum velit commodi. Perspiciatis facilis itaque id temporibus repellat, totam est cumque laboriosam adipisci praesentium tempore deserunt nulla maxime.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
 <style>
    *{
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: rgb(179, 214, 245);
        
        
    }
        .container{
            margin: 3%;
            display: grid;
            position: relative;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
            border: solid 3px black;
            min-height: 450px;
        }
        .left-side{
            background-color: rgb(3, 85, 157);
        }
        .right-side{
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border: solid 3px black;
            position: relative;

        }
        .leftpart1{

        }
        
    </style>
```